# How do I ask wordpress to serve my react app?

Tags: wordpress, reactjs

I am working for an organization that has a wordpress website, I am building a react app that will pull data from the wordpress database through the wordpress API. I am trying to figure out how I can tell wordpress to serve the react app as though the user were simple visiting another page on our site. Is this possible or is my only option to serve the react app on another server?

Comment: Have you tried serving a static html with wordpress? You can basically do the same if your react app is built via create-react-app, where you can simply create an html build (in one command) and let wordpress serve it. There are other more flexible ways like using a reverse proxy such as nginx (if this is an option for you)

Comment: What we all want to know in order to help is how are you building your react app. It is trivial in react to target you app container so depending on your goals you can create a short code or custom template to output your root element.

Comment: yes, I was using create-react-app and after running npm run build I had an html page that I was able to open from my file system into a browser to run my react app just fine. Then I tried to relabel that html to a php and have wordpress serve it, but I got errors that none of the css or js files could be found.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to know about React on a standard server : you will be able to serve your react app separately onto the same server only if you have access to the CLI (command-line). React has to be built by webpack so it'll be impossible to compile, build and serve your react app without using `npm` or `yarn`.

If you don't have access to the CLI, and the Gutenberg wordpress editor is available inside your WordPress, I do suggest you to enqueue React into your theme/custom theme or inside a plugin. A link worth 100 words, please take a look at https://javascriptforwp.com/enqueue-react-in-wordpress/ in order to do it properly.

Basically, you will just have to set an ID or a class name to an element of your DOM body, then React will be mounted on this block and you'll use the ReactDOM render() method from `wp.element` JS object to do so (React lib is available and given from the Gutenberg editor )

Hope this can help you with your question

Comment: I strongly disagree with this piece of advice. Using built in react for you public views means you will forever be using out of date react. Also if you are using Create React App or similar it's not not going to work well if at all.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Thank you for your suggestions. I have decided to create a sub directory in my public_html folder and put the react app there.